# Angular2: Open popup window and load component into it

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I have an angular2 app and I want to open another window and load a component into it. I'm currently using the native JS window.open() method, and passing the result of imperative routing to it:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'uploader',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="startUpload()">
        Upload File
      </button>
    </div>
    `,
  styleUrls: []
})

export class UploaderComponent {
  constructor(private _router: Router) {}

  startUpload(mediaFile: File) {
    let windowObjectReference;

    windowObjectReference = window.open(
      // first param is location
      <string>this._router.navigate(['Feature']),
      'DescriptiveWindowName',
      'width=420,height=230,resizable,scrollbars=yes,status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0'
    );

  }
}
```

The result is that the new window opens correctly, but doesn't route to the intended component. The original window (not the new popped up one) routes to the `Feature` route. The error in the new window:

```
Cannot GET /src/[object%20Object]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The return type of `this._router.navigate(['Feature'])` is `Promise<any>`.  You cannot implicitly convert it to a `string`.  Try hard coding the first parameter to see if it works as intended.  If so, you'll have to figure out another way to provide that parameter if it's dynamic.

Comment: The new window is entirely disconnected from you Angular app. You can use [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between windows.